# Problems with Dirac's Principles of Quantum Mechenics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have been having some trouble reading Principles of Quantum Mechanics by P.A.M.D. I think it all burns down into two aspects.

1) In the theory of representations, the notation is awfull when we have a complete commuting set of observable and each could have a discrete and continuous sets of eigenvalues. The use of integrals (I'm not even sure how to rigorously define mathematically the integral of a ket) and summatories to account for all the possible cases makes for very cumbersome formulae. I love generalization but I also like beautiful formulas, something I thought Paul shared.

2) When going over to the actual content of quantum mechanics, Dirac solves a lot of differential equations on operators and wave functions, as if they were normal functions. Something that bothers me and should be checked more carefully.

Is there any way around both of this problems?

Comment: One way around the first problem is using each operator's *spectral measure*, but it does require a certain level of functional analysis chops. On the plus side, the existence of a spectral measure is all you're really guaranteed by the spectral theorem, so there's that.

Comment: I happen to be reading this book right now.  The notation drives me crazy as well.  I've found that it really pays off to stop every couple of pages and rewrite what's just been said in more modern notation.  As for the lack of mathematical rigor, I'm not taking the trouble to completely rigorize everything, but I'm at least trying to make lists of what would need to be done to make everything rigorous, and I think this is giving me a better understanding of how Dirac saw all this.

Comment: with regard to the second point. Could you especify in what pages those differential equations are?

Comment: For example the whole section 30. The Free Particle. In page 119 (of my edition) he solves the Heisenberg equations of motion for the cartesian coordinate operators of a free particle, something that bothers me since he writes things like $x_t=\frac{c^2p_x}{H}$ by solving the differential equation as if it was and ordinary one but then makes no connection to the definition he gave of functions of observables to explain what dividing by the hamiltonian means.

Comment: I've read a lot of Dirac's papers, Ivan. I think they are dire. I recently came to appreciate that at the time, there was other material that wasn't. See for example https://www.nature.com/articles/119282a0

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I will take a look. I do however want to say that as the years have passed, I've learned to appreciate Dirac's input. If I had to give some advice to myself 4 years ago, take some time to learn proper complex and functional analysis. It will help you immensely in the future! (I've ended up doing some graduate research in stuff involving noncommutate geometry and Tomita-Takesaki Theory)